# Windows 8 does not load correctly

Tags: 12.04, windows

after installing Ubuntu 12.04 the windows system does not boot anymore. I see it in grub and can choose it to start but if so I immediately get a secure boot error and nothing happens further. Any suggestions?

Thx. F.

Comment: Is secure boot enabled?  What exactly is the error?

Answer (score 0):

## 1. The system requires the Ubuntu 64 bit OS program/compatible with windows 8. I would suggest downloading a newer version of Ubuntu 13.10 seems to work best. Write it to disc and choose to install alongside win8 or replace win8. Maybe use it before you install it. Works great once you get used to it.